# Need help understanding div instruction

Tags: assembly

EAX = 0x30323232

ECX = 0x000000F9

div ecx

EAX = 0x00318D0D

EDX = 0x0000008D

I can't understand why the remainder EDX is 8D.
I hope someone can help me with that, Thanks.

Comment: Because that is the remainder when those two numbers are divided.  What else did you expect it to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the remainder equals what's left over after the division, i.e. the difference between the dividend and the product of the divisor and the quotient.

You divided by `0x30323232` by `0xF9` and got a quotient of `0x00318D0D`. If you multiply `0x00318D0D` by `0xF9` you get `0x303231A5`, and therefore the remainder will be `0x30323232 - 0x303231A5` which equals `0x8D`.